# GnuPG is installed but python is not finding it in runtime

Tags: python-3.x, gnupg, pgp

`pip install GnuPG` says that the requirement is already satisfied but when I run a python script with GnuPG it says `GnuPG is not installed`.

Answer (score 6):

In order to fix my environment I had to uninstall pgp and python-gnupg using the pip uninstall commands and then ONLY install python-gnupg. I must have had multiple versions of pgp and python was using the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure about the python and pip version?

try to see pip is referring to which python version and you are running script in which python version, verify if these are the same.

Comment: python --version returns Python 3.7.3;
pip --version returns pip 19.1.1 from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
; Could it be an issue with the Anaconda environment? I am running all commands through Anaconda Prompt

Answer (score 0):

This is what might be happening

- Run pip list to make sure all the libraries you have installed pgp, gnupg...
- Uninstall those libraries `pip unistall library-name`
- Then leave or install `python-gngpg`

In this way you will make sure you are using the right version and your code should work

Comment: Are you saying there's a dependency mismatch?