# RuntimeError: GnuPG is not installed

Tags: python-3.x, gnupg

Requirement: To run python decryption  of the file

I have installed gnupg in the virtual env in MacOS, also `import gnupg` works fine but the second line is throwing an error as below

`>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG() Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/mypython-sPLN-T2A/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gnupg/gnupg.py", line 117, in __init__ super(GPG, self).__init__( File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/mypython-sPLN-T2A/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gnupg/_meta.py", line 182, in __init__ self.binary  = _util._find_binary(binary) File "/Users/.local/share/virtualenvs/mypython-sPLN-T2A/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gnupg/_util.py", line 429, in _find_binary raise RuntimeError("GnuPG is not installed!") RuntimeError: GnuPG is not installed!`

code

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
```

> SOLUTION:

I was finally able to resolve it,

1. Installing `brew install GnuPG`
2. import gnupg
   gpg = gnupg.GPG('/usr/local/bin/gpg')

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763171/gnupg-is-installed-but-python-is-not-finding-it-in-runtime

Comment: I tried out by uninstalling both png and gnupg , but in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed a fresh new Python version ([3.10.0](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/)) and python-gnupg, and it started working:

```
pip3 install python-gnupg
```

Answer (score 0):

Install gnupg package

```
pip install python-gnupg
```

Then explicitly specify the path of gpg binary during object initialization.

```
gpg_binary = '/usr/local/bin/gpg'
gpg = gnupg.GPG(binary=gpg_binary)
```